# collapsing two nodes to one node in py2neo & neo4j

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I need to collapse two nodes to a one node. 
I have gone this far "below" but I could not achieve what i want.

[For example I want to collapse "guy" node and "love" node to a new node preserving the path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D84Ra.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a procedure in [APOC](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) for that : `apoc.refactor.mergeNodes`

Example :

```
MATCH (f:Node {value:'Guy'}), (b:Node {value:'Love'})
WITH * LIMIT 1
CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes([f,b])
YIELD node RETURN node
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning APOC. I tried to do it but got this error: 
 ConstraintError: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.ConstraintViolationTransactionFailureException: Cannot delete node<81>, because it still has relationships. To delete this node, you must first delete its relationships.

Comment: It seems that there is bug on this feature : https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/578. I have updated my response with the mentioned work-around on the issue

Comment: is there a way to update the properties of the new merged node? (while merging)

Comment: yes see the documentation -> https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_merging_nodes

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a new node with the properties you desire and then remove the nodes(guy and love) by using [DETACH DELETE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/delete/).

Comment: thanks techie95. logisima's answer is better in my case.